# PyCharm: Unit testing directory setup with remote interpreter

Tags: docker, unit-testing, ssh, pycharm, interpreter

For years I've been running a Docker container on my local machine and using it as a remote Python interpreter via SSH in PyCharm. This works great (though 2022.2.1 brought a lot of new bugs that have been slowly being ironed out) for running my code! I'm now on 2022.2.3.

However, I'm having issues running unit tests. In the past (i.e. before version 2022.2.1), I could simply right click my tests directory (a direct child of my main project directory) and click `Run Python tests in test...` and it would all work as expected.

Now, though, when I click this, I receive an error message about "No such file or directory."

I've tried everything I can think of- I've setup my path mappings in the Python test run config to exactly match those shown in my Python run config, and have tried every version of directory and subdirectory in the mappings and working directory, but I always receive an error about either having an empty test suite (no tests found), or that the directory "must be in the project."

It seems like no matter what I do, PyCharm is trying to create a temp directory somewhere, or is trying to read from some temp directory that I never specified, because I see errors this like:

`AssertionError: /tmp/pycharm_project_405/docker/tests: No such file or directory`

Yet I never created, specified, or requested a temp directory of any sort, let alone one named `/tmp/pycharm_project_405/`; this is a mystery to me.

PyCharm with an SSH interpreter is rapidly becoming unusable for me and my team because we cannot figure out how to set this up. Can anybody please offer some guidance on what we need to do?

Thank you all so very much!

I tried:

- Changing run config for Python tests to match the working directory and path mapping of Python run configs (which work)
- Directly specifying the path to the tests *from the container's perspective*
- Setting up run config templates
- Specifying one directory up/down from the actual tests

Expected:
Unit tests to be found and run as they were in previous versions of PyCharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

1. Create a run config for testing
2. In the testing run config, set Target: to Custom
3. Set the correct remote interpreter
4. Set Working directory to the test folder
5. Set TWO path mappings: 1) Map the code directory (in my case, the parent directory of the tests folder) and 2) Map the test directory itself

Voila!!!